Mock Function in Custom Hook
New to JavaScript, React, and Jest. I have been struggling with writing a Jest test for the sort functionality of a custom hook.
I am basically trying to mock getRegionOptions() so that it returns ["C", "B", "A"] and then the hook useRegionOptions returns ["A", "B", "C"].  Not sure if this is even possible.
I have been reading several posts and trying a few things, but I am not getting it to work.
I apologize if there are typos in the code below. I had to strip corporate info and reproduce locally as I can’t post to StackOverflow from the company network.
Custom Hook:
export constant useRegionOptions = (list, client) => {

    const { setFieldTouched } = useFormikContext();
    const [regionOptions, setRegionOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getRegionOptions() {
            return (
                await fetch(
                        'url/region/${client}',
                        {
                            method: 'GET'
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            }
                        }
                    )
                ).json();
        }

    if (!!client) {
        getRegionOptions()
            .then(regionList => {
                setRegionOptions([...regionList].sort());
                setFieldTouched('region');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
        }
    }, [client]);

    return {
        regionOptions,
        setRegionOptions
    };
};

The test is something like this:
describe('useRegionOptions', () => {
    it('should list elements alphabetically', async () => {

        global.fetch = jest.fn( () =>
            Promise.resolve( {
                json: () => Promise.resolve({['C', 'B', 'A'] }),
            })
        );

        const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useRegionOptions('list', 'client'))

        await waitForNextUpdate();

        expect(result.current.value).toBe(['A', 'B', 'C']);

    })

});



What do you actually want to test? I think what you want to test is that fetch gets called with the appropriate client parameter, correct?

The hook gets a region list from an endpoint and sorts it.  Trying to mock the endpoint call so that it returns an unsorted list and verify the hook returns a sorted list.

Your question does not mention what is wrong with your current solution. However, I can give some advice that using Mock Service Worker is the most modern way of mocking network calls. It can be bound to jest. See https://mswjs.io/docs/integrations/node/#test-runner and https://github.com/mswjs/examples/blob/main/examples/with-jest-jsdom/README.md

However that said, the assertion toBe should be toEqual. The former checks referential equality and will always be false in this case. You need toEqual.
